# Python3 security Webcam

Tags: image, python-3.x, security

I am new here and in Python 3.
How can I add a wireless security Camera in Opencv?

How I can send a mail with a picture and a text?

Comment: Welcome.  Please take a look at [this help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the types of questions that should be asked here. For example "how hard is it to do X?" is not a great question because there is likely no good single answer.  Try to break your problem up into separate pieces and ask specific programming questions about each piece.

Comment: ok thanks for answer